# PHRETS - Pulling out MLS agent informations

Tags: php, rets

```
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("User",11,"(2699=1900-01-01+)");
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
    echo print_r($listing);
}
```

Trying to pull out all MLS agents using these settings, but just cant get to see anything at all, i have tried so many options, but nothing pass on.

```
The Field : [2699] => LastLoginDate
(Pulled out directly from get metadatatable)
```

I can perfectly pull out listings without any issues using the same code above with different classname and codes. The User just wont go through, anything i am missing ?  Thanks alot

Here is my result from metadata tables (So that you see that my User and 11 are good)

```
  Array
   (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [Resource] => DeletedListing
        [Data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 1021
                        [VisibleName] => DeletedListing
                        [StandardName] => 
                        [Description] => Deleted Listings
                        [TableVersion] => 28.63.49757
                        [TableDate] => Thu, 28 Jul 2011 05:35:57 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Resource] => Office
        [Data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 12
                        [VisibleName] => OFF
                        [StandardName] => Office
                        [Description] => Office
                        [TableVersion] => 37.45.13672
                        [TableDate] => Tue, 13 May 2014 15:34:32 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Resource] => Property
        [Data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 1
                        [VisibleName] => RES
                        [StandardName] => ResidentialProperty
                        [Description] => Residential
                        [TableVersion] => 37.91.89015
                        [TableDate] => Sun, 06 Jul 2014 18:16:55 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 2
                        [VisibleName] => CON
                        [StandardName] => 
                        [Description] => Condominium
                        [TableVersion] => 37.59.63841
                        [TableDate] => Fri, 30 May 2014 10:24:01 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 3
                        [VisibleName] => MUL
                        [StandardName] => MultiFamily
                        [Description] => Multifamily
                        [TableVersion] => 37.59.63864
                        [TableDate] => Fri, 30 May 2014 10:24:24 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 4
                        [VisibleName] => LOT
                        [StandardName] => LotsAndLand
                        [Description] => Lots
                        [TableVersion] => 37.59.63885
                        [TableDate] => Fri, 30 May 2014 10:24:45 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 5
                        [VisibleName] => FAR
                        [StandardName] => 
                        [Description] => Farm
                        [TableVersion] => 37.59.63903
                        [TableDate] => Fri, 30 May 2014 10:25:03 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 6
                        [VisibleName] => RNT
                        [StandardName] => 
                        [Description] => Rental
                        [TableVersion] => 37.59.63920
                        [TableDate] => Fri, 30 May 2014 10:25:20 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 10
                        [VisibleName] => ICI
                        [StandardName] => 
                        [Description] => Commercial
                        [TableVersion] => 37.59.63952
                        [TableDate] => Fri, 30 May 2014 10:25:52 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 13
                        [VisibleName] => XProp
                        [StandardName] => CommonInterest
                        [Description] => Cross-Property and Open House
                        [TableVersion] => 37.58.83323
                        [TableDate] => Thu, 29 May 2014 12:02:03 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Resource] => User
        [Data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ClassName] => 11
                        [VisibleName] => USE
                        [StandardName] => Agent
                        [Description] => Member
                        [TableVersion] => 37.50.77785
                        [TableDate] => Tue, 20 May 2014 04:16:25 GMT
                        [UpdateVersion] => 
                        [UpdateDate] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Meta Table for the Ressource USER and class 11

```
Array
(
    [sysid] => sysid
    [1662] => Address 1
    [1663] => WorkPhone
    [1664] => EMail Address
    [1665] => Agent Home Page
    [1666] => Access Flag
    [1669] => CellPhone
    [1670] => PagerPhone
    [1671] => City
    [1672] => State
    [1673] => MiddleName
    [1674] => NickName
    [1675] => Comments
    [1676] => OfficePID
    [1677] => OfficeContactNotes
    [1678] => SecurityType
    [1679] => Yellow Pages Flag (Old)
    [1680] => Office Phone (Unused)
    [1681] => Office Fax (Old)
    [1682] => BillingAddress1
    [1683] => BillingAddress2
    [1684] => BillingCity
    [1685] => BillingState
    [1686] => BillingZipCode
    [1687] => BillingPhone
    [1688] => BillingFaxPhone
    [1689] => DeliveryAddress1
    [1690] => DeliveryAddress2
    [1691] => DeliveryCity
    [1692] => DeliveryState
    [1693] => DeliveryZipCode
    [1694] => DeliveryPhone
    [1695] => DeliveryFaxPhone
    [1696] => DeliveryPID
    [1697] => DeliveryRoute
    [1698] => DeliveryStop
    [1699] => DeliveryNotes
    [1700] => DeliveryCommAdrs
    [1701] => KeyCardID
    [1702] => AffiliateType
    [1703] => OfficeVoiceExt
    [1704] => AccountingNum
    [1705] => OtherLicenseNum
    [1706] => NRDSMemberID
    [1707] => PublishingProd1
    [1708] => PublishingProd2
    [1709] => PublishingProd3
    [1710] => PublishingProd4
    [1711] => Access Flag Date (Old)
    [1712] => NetMLSAccess
    [1713] => DataLinkAccess
    [1714] => CensusGroup
    [1715] => CensusTract
    [1716] => CensusBlock
    [1717] => BSMemberPrimaryIndicator
    [1718] => Roster Flag
    [1719] => Yellow Page Flag
    [1720] => Direct Line
    [1721] => BSGender
    [1722] => BSHomeZIPCode
    [1723] => BSHomeZIPCode6
    [1724] => BSMailAddress
    [1725] => BSMailAttnCareOf
    [1726] => BSMailCity
    [1727] => BSMailState
    [1728] => BSMailZIPCode
    [1729] => BSMailZIPCode6
    [1730] => BSPreferredMail
    [1731] => BSPreferredPublication
    [1732] => BSHomeAreaCode
    [1733] => Home Phone Number (Old)
    [1734] => BSPersonalFaxArea
    [1735] => Personal Fax (Old)
    [1736] => BSPreferredFax
    [1737] => BSOfficeID
    [1738] => Member Class
    [1739] => BSJoinedDate
    [1740] => BSOrientationDate
    [1741] => BSStatus
    [1742] => BSStatusDate
    [1743] => BSPreviousNonMember
    [1744] => BSDuesWaivedLocal
    [1745] => BSDuesWaivedState
    [1746] => Board
    [1747] => BSSocialSecurityNumber
    [1748] => MLXchange # of Accesses
    [1749] => BSBirthDate
    [1750] => BSTransferDate
    [1751] => BSStopMail
    [1752] => BSJunkMailFlag
    [1753] => BSOnlineStatus
    [1754] => Access Flag Date
    [1755] => BSPrimaryAssociationID
    [1756] => BSSecondaryAssociationID1
    [1757] => BSSecondaryAssociationID2
    [1758] => BSSecondaryAssociationID3
    [1759] => BSPrimaryStateAssocID
    [1760] => BSSecondaryStateAssocID1
    [1761] => BSSecondaryStateAssocID2
    [1762] => BSSecondaryStateAssocID3
    [1763] => BSAffiliationCode#1
    [1764] => BSAffiliationCode#2
    [1765] => BSAffiliationCode#3
    [1766] => BSAffiliationCode#4
    [1767] => BSAffiliationCode#5
    [1768] => BSAffiliationCode#6
    [1769] => BSAffiliationCode#7
    [1770] => BSAffiliationCode#8
    [1771] => BSAffiliationCode#9
    [1772] => BSAffiliationCode#10
    [1773] => BSAffiliationCode#11
    [1774] => BSAffiliationCode#12
    [1775] => BSDesignationDate#1
    [1776] => BSDesignationCode#1
    [1777] => BSDesignationCode#2
    [1778] => BSDesignationDate#2
    [1779] => BSDesignationCode#3
    [1780] => BSDesignationDate#3
    [1781] => BSDesignationCode#4
    [1782] => BSDesignationDate#4
    [1783] => BSDesignationCode#5
    [1784] => BSDesignationDate#5
    [1785] => BSDesignationCode#6
    [1786] => BSDesignationDate#6
    [1787] => BSDesignationCode#7
    [1788] => BSDesignationDate#7
    [1789] => BSDesignationCode#8
    [1790] => BSDesignationDate#8
    [1791] => BSDesignationCode#9
    [1792] => BSDesignationDate#9
    [1793] => BSDesignationCode#10
    [1794] => BSDesignationDate#10
    [1795] => BSDesignationCode#11
    [1796] => BSDesignationDate#11
    [1797] => BSDesignationCode#12
    [1798] => BSDesignationDate#12
    [1799] => BSPrimaryFieldofBusiness
    [1800] => BSSecondaryFieldofBus1
    [1801] => BSSecondaryFieldofBus2
    [1802] => BSSecondaryFieldofBus3
    [1803] => User Title
    [1804] => BSPointOfEntry
    [1805] => BSEMailAddress
    [1806] => BSMLSNumber
    [1807] => Altaira Multi-Login Flag YN
    [1808] => BSStopFaxCode
    [1809] => Agent Extension
    [1810] => BSReinstatementCode
    [1811] => BSReinstatementDate
    [1812] => BSNARDuesPaid
    [1813] => BSStateDuesPaid
    [1814] => Board Old
    [1815] => Address 2
    [1816] => Address 3
    [1817] => Entry Date
    [1818] => First Name
    [1819] => Personal Fax
    [1820] => Last Name
    [1821] => Last Transaction Code
    [1822] => Last Transaction Date
    [1823] => Office Code
    [1824] => Password
    [1825] => Rdfsetdate
    [1826] => Record Delete Flag
    [1827] => Roster Flag (Old)
    [1828] => Primary User Class
    [1829] => Member Code
    [1830] => Agent ID
    [1831] => User Title (Old)
    [1832] => Home Phone 
    [1833] => Postal Code
    [2310] => RegBoard
    [2414] => User Full Name
    [2415] => User Company Name
    [2416] => User Address1
    [2417] => User Address2
    [2418] => User City
    [2419] => User State
    [2420] => User Zip
    [2421] => User Work Phone
    [2422] => User Cell Phone
    [2423] => User Pager-PIN
    [2424] => User Fax
    [2425] => User 800 Phone
    [2426] => User Primary Email
    [2427] => User Cell Email
    [2428] => User Web URL
    [2429] => User Email Signature
    [2468] => MLX Type
    [2469] => SecondaryBoardID
    [2473] => License Type
    [2513] => MDCAuditLevel
    [2514] => AgentFullName
    [2515] => ProNDREmailAddress
    [2530] => SuspensionType
    [2531] => SuspensionDate
    [2555] => PriviledgedSSOUser
    [2556] => Designation
    [2557] => EmailSignature
    [2572] => FirmCode
    [2573] => FirmName
    [2585] => DrivingLatitude
    [2586] => DrivingLongitude
    [2598] => AgentLicense
    [2689] => ListingServiceNameAbbrev
    [2692] => Member CREA ID
    [2699] => LastLoginDate
)
```

I must specifiy that this exact request works for pulling out properties :

```
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property",1,"(105=2012-01-01+)");
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
    echo print_r($listing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the MetadataTable for the Resource User and ClassName 11.

I really don't think this is correct

`(2699=1900-01-01+)`

Are you sure it isn't:

`(LastLoginDate=1900-01-01+)`

Comment: I have Tried using the given example without any sucess. Any idea why this is giving me so much trouble ?

Comment: Any updates on this ? I am still unable to pull out the data... Thanks again

Comment: Can you please show all the metadata info including data type for each column in the Resource User and ClassName 11. You don't need to show all the columns just the 2699 column.

Comment: I have included both tables up in the original post. Thanks !

Comment: Right, but it doesn't have the data type.

Maybe try:

```(2699=1900-01-01T00:00:00+)```

More [dmql help](https://www.flexmls.com/support/rets/tutorials/dmql/)